# Unable to connect to Vagrant private network from host

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, virtualbox, vagrant

I have a vagrant virtual box up and running.  So far I have been unable to connect to the web server.  here is the start up:

```
[jesse@Athens VVV-1.1]$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    default: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
    default: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
    default: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you see
    default: shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
    default: virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
    default: your host and reload your VM.
    default: 
    default: Guest Additions Version: 4.2.0
    default: VirtualBox Version: 4.3
==> default: Setting hostname...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /home/jesse/vagrant/vvvStable/VVV-1.1
    default: /srv/www => /home/jesse/vagrant/vvvStable/VVV-1.1/www
    default: /srv/config => /home/jesse/vagrant/vvvStable/VVV-1.1/config
    default: /srv/database => /home/jesse/vagrant/vvvStable/VVV-1.1/database
    default: /var/lib/mysql => /home/jesse/vagrant/vvvStable/VVV-1.1/database/data
==> default: VM already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use `--provision` to force it
==> default: Checking for host entries
```

on my host console, ip addr show yields:

```
4: vboxnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000                                       
    link/ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff                                                                         
5: vboxnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000                                      
    link/ether 0a:00:27:00:00:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

on the guest it yields:

```
vagrant@vvv:~$ ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:12:96:98 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe12:9698/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:2c:d4:3e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.50.4/24 brd 192.168.50.255 scope global eth1
```

For now, all I want to do is access the web server on the virtual machine, whatever way works.  I have tried a variety of things, just shooting in the dark.  I would be happy to provide any specific info.  Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Better to paste the networking block of your `Vagrantfile`.

Comment: vboxnet0 and vboxnet1 are down.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1214376/74576 is the setup that worked for me.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Based on the output provided, the box has 2 network interfaces, 1 is the default NAT and the other private - ask you said.

The reason why you are not able to access the web site hosted within the VM thru the private interface: it could be that host `eth0` or `wlan0` IP address is not in the same network as the private interface -> `192.168.50.4/24` and there is no route.

To access the the site hosted by the web server within the guest, you have the following options:

#### 1. NAT port forwarding

Forward the web port, e.g. 80 to host's 8080 (you can't use 80 because it is a privileged port on *NIX). Add the following

```rb
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080,
    auto_correct: true
end
```

> NOTE: auto_correct will resolve port conflicts if the port on host is already in use.

DO a `vagrant reload` and you'll be able to access the site via `http://localhost:8080/`

#### 2. Public Network (VirtualBox Bridged networking)

Add a public network interface

```rb
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "public_network"
end
```

Get the IP of VM after it is up and running, port forwarding does NOT apply to bridged networking. So you'll be accessing the site by using `http://IP_ADDR`, if within the VM it binds to 80, otherwise specify the port.

Comment: Thanks Terry, both of the options you mentioned worked.

Comment: I've been struggling for a while on this. The auto_correct did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: I tried the first solution and it solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: you save my life <3

Answer (score 20):

One more possibility just for future reference.

Normally when you create VMs using private networking, Vagrant (Virtualbox? not sure) creates corresponding entries in the host's routing table. You can see these using

```
netstat -rn
```

Somehow my host had gotten into a state where creating the VMs did not result in new routes appearing in the routing table, with the corresponding inability to connect. Again you can see the routes *not* appearing using the command above.

Creating the route manually allowed me to reach the VMs. For example:

```
sudo route -nv add -net 10.0.4 -interface vboxnet
```

(Substitute the appropriate network and interface.) But I didn't want to have to do that.

Based on [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/78365/how-to-reload-default-mac-osx-routing-table-without-rebooting), I tried restarting my host and Vagrant started automatically creating the routing table entries again.

Not sure exactly what the issue was, but hopefully this helps somebody.

Comment: just simply adding the route worked for me! thanks for the help.

Comment: route: invalid option -- 'i'
route: invalid option -- 't'
route: invalid option -- 'r'
route: invalid option -- 'f'
route: invalid option -- 'a'
route: invalid option -- 'c'

Answer (score 6):

## Your interface is down

I had the same issue.  It was my vboxnet0 interface who was down.  Within the listing of `ip addr` you have  `<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>` for your interface but it should be `<BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>`.

That's mean you interface is down.

You can confirm with `sudo ifconfig`.  The interface will not be shown but if you add `-a` you will see it :  `sudo ifconfig -a`.

### how to bring it up

So to bring it up you can do :

```
sudo ifconfig vbox
```

OR

```
sudo ip link set vboxnet0 up
```

Both works.

Comment: Thanks - this was exactly the problem I was having installing vagrant on a new machine (Linux Mint 18.1). I got the interface up using `sudo ip link set vboxnet0 up` as above.

I've never had this problem before and I'd like to know why it happened.

I had trouble with some missing Gems when running `Vagrant up` which took a while to resolve and wonder if this might have been a cause?

Comment: Hard to know. For my part i think i upgraded virtualbox from 5.0 to 5.1 but i noticed the bug many days after. It could be kernel upgrade too.  I'm also on LM18.

Comment: I think it was a bug in Virtual Box 5.1.24 - I upgraded to 5.1.26 and it appears to have fixed the issue (but I haven't restarted my laptop or vagrant since then so can't confirm)

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog#v26

Linux hosts: properly bring up host-only network interfaces with iproute (5.1.24 regression; bug #16911)

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you could use manual port forwarding via SSH (SSH tunneling):

```
ssh -L 80:127.0.0.1:80 vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222
```

That binds host port 80 to VM port 80 via your SSH session to the VM.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up getting the private network to work as well by deleting it within Virtual Box.  When I recreated it again with vagrant up, the ip config became:

```
vboxnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.50.1/24 brd 192.168.50.255 scope global vboxnet0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: This needs more specific steps to be useful.

Comment: I did the equivalent in parallels. Opened Parallels Desktop -> Preferences -> Network Tab, then deleted the vagrant-vnet0 entry. After doing a vagrant reload, the correct interface was added to the host's ipconfig.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue on my Mac. VirtualBox uses host only for private networks.  To use as an internal network I had to add this to the private network configuration:

```
"virtualbox__intnet: true"
```

Comment: some clarification on where you made this change would help

Comment: Thank you! This is finally the answer I've been looking for. 

Some clarification on how to use this is that you add an entry for a private network to your Vagrantfile. Such as: `config.vm.network "private_network", virtualbox__intnet: true` More info here: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/providers/virtualbox/networking#virtualbox-internal-network

Answer (score 2):

This may not apply exactly, but "private network" in the title brought me here and others may benefit that are trying to run multiple guest boxes on Mac OS X:

I use "private_network" **and don't do any port forwarding.** I.e. I access my VMs by hosts like "project1.local", "project2.local".

So, I was surprised when I tried to launch a second box (a scotch/box ubuntu for LAMP) and **it refused to launch with an error** (excerpt):

```
"...The forwarded port to 2222 is already in use on the host machine..."
```

The error message's proposed solution doesn't work. I.e. add this to your Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22, host: 1234
#Where 1234 would be a different port.
```

I am not sure why it happens because I've run multiples before (but not scotch/box). The problem is that even if you use private_network, Vagrant uses port forwarding for SSH.

The solution is to set ports SPECIFICALLY FOR SSH by adding this to your Vagrant files:

```
# Specify SSH config explicitly with unique host port for each box
config.vm.network :forwarded_port,
  guest: 22,
  host: 1234,
  id: "ssh",
  auto_correct: true
```

Note: auto_correct may make non-unique port #s work, but I haven't tested that.

Now, you can run multiple VMs at the same time using private networking.

(Thanks to Aaron Aaron and his posting here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vagrant-up/HwqFegoCXOc)

Answer (score 1):

Was having the same issue with Arch (2017-01-01). Had to install `net-tools`: `sudo pacman -S net-tools`

Virtual Box 5.1.12r112440, Vagrant 1.9.1.

Comment: For me on openSUSE Tumbleweed the package to install is net-tools-deprecated. This has solved the problem for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have set a private network in for your vagrant machine

If that ip is not visible then ssh to your vagrant machine and fire this command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

**Check to stop your firewall and iptables too**

Comment: thanks! using libvirt here with  CentOS 7. Worked for me. Every time I create a new machine I had to restart the network service. In CentOs just do `sudo /etc/init.d/network restart`