# Expose Vagrant VM to network when using NFS and private_network

Tags: ruby, vagrant

I have a multi-machine Vagrant setup.  Using NFS and `private_network` I can get everything to work that I need (Drupal, PHP, etc) EXCEPT allowing someone down the hall to visit a web app running on my VM.  I understand that `private_network` makes it impossible to connect to the VMs from the outside world.

Is there a way to create both a private AND public network so that all VMS EXCEPT the load balancer are private and the load balancer is accessible via the host's ip?

```rb
hosts = {
  "wloadlocal" => "192.168.33.10",
  "wweblocal1" => "192.168.33.11",
  "wweblocal2" => "192.168.33.12",
  "wwhlocal" => "192.168.33.13",
}

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  hosts.each do |name, ip|
    config.vm.define name do |machine|
      machine.vm.box = "precise32"
      machine.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box"
      machine.vm.hostname = "%s.example.org" % name
      machine.vm.network :private_network, ip: ip
      machine.vm.network "public_network"
      machine.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
          v.name = name
          v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", 200]
      end
      if name == "wloadlocal"
        machine.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8880
      end
    end
    #sync folders
    config.vm.synced_folder "~/data", "/data", type: "nfs"
  end
end
```

Edit #1

On Vagrant's [NFS doc page](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/nfs.html) it states that when using VirtualBox and NFS you must use private_network:

> If you're using the VirtualBox provider, you'll also need to make sure
>   you have a private network set up. This is due to a limitation of
>   VirtualBox's built-in networking. With VMware, you do not need this.

I need to use NFS for performance reasons but I also would like to be able to share apps running in the VMs over a local network when needed.  Is this possible?

Comment: P.S. To all the closers: Vagrant is a _dev_ tool, it's not a networking/sysadmin tool. Its purpose is to enable devs to set up VM recipes that work identically for all devs in your team.

Comment: While Vagrant has an API, how to set up the internal network the way the OP wants could be a better fit on [su]. Once that configuration is known then putting it into code should be easy. Toward the OPs question, I don't think you can create two types of networks internally.

Comment: I think this bouncing between sites is getting just silly. Let the question be. It's not in the scope of Super User to do Vagrant configurations.

Comment: @frodopwns it should be fully possible to have multiple networks, like [explained in the manual](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/basic_usage.html) ("Multiple Networks") as well as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23497855/unable-to-connect-to-vagrant-private-network-from-host). Do you have a problem with those solutions? If so, can you detail what it is you're having problems with?

Comment: @eis the poster in the linked question doesn't have the same issue I have.  He was unable to access his VM when using a private network.  I can access mine.  I need a way to have both NFS (which requires a private network) and allow outside users to access a port on one of my VMs.

Comment: The best answer I have found so far is Vagrant Share but I'm open to other suggestions.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young: But this question isn't about achieving a desired configuration using vagrant.  He doesn't know what configuration he wants.  See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275041/103167

Comment: @Ben I don't have a desired configuration I have a desired outcome.

Comment: @frodopwns: That's exactly why it is off-topic here.  Finding a configuration that provides your outcome is a networking question.  Automating that configuration, once you find it, using Vagrant will be an on-topic question for SO.

Comment: @Ben I don't think your differentiation makes any difference here.  Have you worked with Vagrant?

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way I could find around this was to use multiple networks as mentioned in one of the comments. So my config ends up looking like this:

```
  config.vm.define :host01 do |host01|
    postgres01.vm.network :private_network, ip: '192.168.37.2'
    config.vm.network "public_network"
    host01.vm.hostname = 'host01'
    configure_vm(host01)
  end
```

Then I did `vagrant ssh host01` to look up the public ip which ended up being `192.168.0.102` on my network. Now I can access that ip from my host. Note there are some [caveats](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/public_network.html) to using the public network feature.